# python sqlite3 execute method slow

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using Python 2.7.5 in Spyder along with Sqlite3 3.6.21. I have noticed the execute method to be pretty slow, pretty much regardless of the size of the database I'm creating. After doing some research, no solution really works for me:

- Python 3 is not supported by Spyder yet
- updating the Sqlite3 version does not work (replacing the dll file causes problems)

Is there a way around this? If any more details are needed, I'm glad to elaborate further.

Comment: spyder works perfectly  fine with python 3.4 (on ubuntu that is; wouldn't know for other platforms but i'm sure that works as well - oh, you mention  dlls; windows then?).

Comment: here you have python 3.4 downloads for spyder on windows: https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads

Comment: Are you using transactions properly?

Comment: @hiro protagonist: Yes, I forgot to mention, I'm using Windows 7. Thanks for the link, I'll look into it, although I'm trying to avoid using Python 3, since I'll have to adjust my code a bit (which I'm aware is stupid - this needs to be done sooner or later).

Comment: @ Colonel Thirty Two: the code I wrote was pretty ad-hoc, but basically I'm using a bunch of elementary "execute" statements. Concretely, I have reocurring blocks of code which consist of
- execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ... ")
- execute("CREATE TABLE ...")
- execute("INSERT INTO ...")

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, inspired by Colonel Thirty Two's comment above, I just realized that I need to wrap all my operations into one transaction. This was trivial to implement and improved overall efficiency drastically. Thanks once again!